# Encoding text to file / reading encoded text correctly to eradicate the Â symbol?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, utf-8, encode

Basically in my student data I am having an issue where by I am getting weird sumbols in my data as you can see: `MAIN Â£1.00`when it should show `MAIN £1.00`

Below is a snippet of my code what scrapes a website for certain student information for their student discounts and eventually writes it to file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-             
totals = main.find_all('p')
for total in totals:
    if total .find(text=re.compile("Main:")):
        total = total.get_text()
        if u"Main £" in total:
            pull1 = re.search(r'(MAIN) (\D\w+\D\d+)', total)
            pull2 = re.search(r'(MAINER) (\D\w+\D\d+)', total)
            if pull1:
                rpr_data.append(pull1.group(0).title())
                print pull1.group(0).title()
            if pull2:
                rpr_data.append(pull2.group(0).title())
                print pull2.group(0).title()
with open('RPR.txt','w') as rpr_file:
    rpr_file.write('\n'.join(rpr_data).encode("UTF-8"))
```

When I try and re-use this data in the script [Matching three variables from textfile to csv and writing variables to the csv on matched rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173498/matching-three-variables-from-textfile-to-csv-and-writing-variables-to-the-csv-o) even though the data in the text file has no weird `Â` symbol when it writes to CSV the symbol comes back...

How can I permanently eradicate this `Â` symbol correctly?

Comment: First, are you sure the script is actually saved as a UTF-8 text file, rather than Latin-1/cp1252/etc.? (Just putting a coding declaration comment at the top doesn't change the coding your text editors uses, except for emacs, it just lies to Python…)

Comment: Also, _where_ are you seeing that `MAIN Â£1.00`? In Notepad.exe after opening `RPR.txt`? Or…?

Comment: @abarnert I am seeing that on certain prints. Using the line `total = total.get_text()` somehow strips the `Â` symbol but after I run the matching script in the other thread I get the `Â` re-appear in the column(s)

Comment: Ah, that's because your terminal's character set is Latin-1/cp1252/etc., and Python is printing UTF-8 at it. (Can you please tell us what platform you're on and, if not Windows, what terminal you use, so I don't have to keep guessing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting extra `Â` characters before various western-european characters is almost always a sign of interpreting UTF-8 as Latin-1 (or cp1252 or some other "extended Latin-1" charset).*

That could be you receiving UTF-8 input and trying to process it as Latin-1, or you generating UTF-8 output that someone *else* is trying to process as Latin-1.

---

If you're seeing these in the output file, the most likely possibility is that your code is doing everything right every step of the way, and generating a perfectly good UTF-8 file… and then you're trying to view that file on a Windows machine whose OEM code page is 1252 in a program like Notepad that defaults to the OEM code page.

If that's it, there are two possibilities:

1. Don't do that. View the file as UTF-8. You can tell Notepad to open a file as UTF-8 instead of the default. Or you can use a different editor/viewer.
2. If you want the file to be viewable as cp1252, or as "whatever the OEM code page is on this machine", save it that way—e.g., change the last line to use `encode("cp1252")`.

---

If you're seeing them in the `print` statements, the most likely possibility is that your code is doing everything right, but your terminal is a Windows DOS prompt that's again set to code page 1252. See [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) and [Windows cmd encoding change causes Python crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash/3259271) for all the different things that can be wrong here and how to work around them.

---

* You can see this from a quick line of Python: `u'\u00a3'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1') == u'\u00c2\u00a3'`. That `u'\u00c2'` is `Â`. Going the *other* way can never cause this problem: `u'\u00a3'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` will instead raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: The original encoding is: `iso-8859-1`

Comment: @Hyflex: The original encoding of _what_? The source code file? Some input file that you're not showing us here? Anyway, `iso-8859-1` is the same thing as Latin-1.

Comment: The website in which some of my data is scraped from in the source it says `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`

Comment: Latin-1 indeed. `>>> print "MAIN £1.00".decode('latin-1') ->
MAIN Â£1.00`

Comment: The data is pulled directly from urllib using the following line: `html = urllib2.urlopen("xx.xx.xxx.xx", timeout=10).read().decode('Latin-1')` (the web-address can't be shown as it's a direct IP) but if I print the html it still shows the wierd A

Comment: @Hyflex: This may seem surprising, but that's probably a red herring. You haven't shown us how you scraped the data, but you must have properly accounted for the Latin-1 on that end. Interpreting a UTF-8 `£` as Latin-1 will give you `Â£`, but interpreting a Latin-1 `£` as UTF-8 will give you a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: @Hyflex: Beat me by a millisecond… Anyway, yeah, that proves it that you _are_ properly accounting for the Latin-1 on the input end. The problem is that you aren't properly accounting for the Latin-1-or-similar on the _output_ end.

Comment: @abarnet I've changed them all to Latin-1 but if I print `total` before the line `total = total.get_text()` I get the `Â£` everywhere still... :/

Comment: @Hyflex: You've changed _what_ all to Latin-1? Meanwhile, if the problem is on printing, did you read the questions/answers I linked to? There's way too much to explain in a comment.

Comment: @Hyflex: Also, if you won't answer questions, it makes it very hard to help you. I asked you before for your platform, terminal, versions, etc. Without any of that information, I have to try to guess, and to write vague answers that make sense for any possibility.

Comment: Windows, IdleGUI Python 2.7... I don't know exactly what else you need.